# ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, virtualenv, gpu

Possible duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558707/tensorflow-importerror-libcusolver-so-8-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no)
I have a gpu account to whom I connect through putty (ssh login). I have created a virtualenv there and I am installing tenorflow through pip for gpu. Everything works fine, when I run command

```
$ pip list
```

following list is being shown:

```
 backports.weakref (1.0rc1)
 bleach (1.5.0)
 funcsigs (1.0.2)
 html5lib (0.9999999)
 Markdown (2.6.8)
 mock (2.0.0)
 numpy (1.13.1)
 olefile (0.44)
 pbr (3.1.1)
 Pillow (4.2.1)
 pip (9.0.1)
 protobuf (3.3.0)
 setuptools (36.0.1)
 six (1.10.0)
 tensorflow-gpu (1.2.1)
 Werkzeug (0.12.2)
 wheel (0.29.0)
```

But when I run:

```
$ python
>>> import tensorflow
```

It shows the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nauman/junaid/final/test/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/nauman/junaid/final/test/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/nauman/junaid/final/test/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
  raise ImportError(msg)
  ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nauman/junaid/final/test/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/nauman/junaid/final/test/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
  <module>
  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/nauman/junaid/final/test/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in 
  swig_import_helper
  _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, 
  description)
  ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such 
  file or directory
  Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
  See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
  for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
  above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have also set my environment variables like this:

```
  export CUDA_HOME=/opt/cuda
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib64:$CUDA_HOME/extras/CUPTI/lib64"
```

Moreover, I found that libcusolver.so.8.0 is not there, while libcusolver.so.7.5
is there in cuda/lib64/.
Somehow tensorflow is finding wrong file or I ain't know nothing. 
Any help would be appreciated as I am new to all this stuff. 
Python version: 2.7
OS: Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue. Actually I have cuda 7.5 installed and I was installing latest tensorflow version which probably support cuda 8.0.
So I downgraded.

```
 pip install --upgrade \ https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: I also just installed tensorflow version 1.2.0 instead of 1.3.0 to use cuda 7.5 with `pip install tensorflow==1.2.0`. Note that I left `tensorflow-gpu` at 1.3.0

Comment: @ben26941 my guess is that you are using cuda-9.0 . In that case try `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-dev` (if you are using an Ubuntu distribution)

Answer (score 5):

This may be connected to the incorrect linking of your libraries.
Simply run `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64`. It solved for me.

If you need to know more: [`ldconfig` `man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig).

Answer (score 0):

If you installed `tensorflow-gpu` by using `pip` with prebuilt `.whl`, the cuda version were fixed. As far as I know, starting `0.11.0rc1`, all the prebuilt packages are now built for `cuda 8`. So there are two ways to solve the problem:

1. install `cuda 8` for the prebuilt packages `tensorflow-gpu >= 0.11.orc1`
2. keep `cuda 7.5` stay, then build `tensorflow-gpu` from source code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cuda-9.0 try `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-dev` (if you are using an Ubuntu distribution)