# ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0 Anything wrong with my path variables

Tags: tensorflow

This is the only error I am recieving when trying to import tensorflow. I know this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558707/tensorflow-importerror-libcusolver-so-8-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no) has already been asked before but the solution did not work for me so I am wondering what to do.

I see this file in the lib64 folder in cuda so I thought it was just an issue of having the wrong path so I added the following paths but it didn't solve it
The paths I have in my ~/.bashrc:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
```

Relevent system info:
geforce gtx 1080
cuda8.0 cudNN 5.1
ubuntu 16.04 LTS
python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Check libcusolver.so.8.0 is present in /usr/local/cuda/lib64, 
if not check cuda path is cuda-8.0 if it is then use this path /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 if not try install cuda again.

Comment: the file was in cuda-8.0/lib64 so I updated my path to usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 but it did not fix the error.  Will try re-installing later...