# How to develop for tensor flow with gpu without a gpu

Tags: tensorflow

I have previously asked if it is possible to run tensor flow with gpu support on a cpu.  I was told that it is possible and the basic code to switch which device I want to use but not how to get the initial code working on a computer that doesn't have a gpu at all.  For example I would like to train on a computer that has a NVidia gpu but program on a laptop that only has a cpu.  How would I go about doing this?  I have tried just writing the code as normal but it crashes before I can even switch which device I want to use. I am using Python on Linux.

Comment: What programming language?  What OS?

Comment: @Neil I have edited the post with the info you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread might be helpful: [Tensorflow: ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558707/tensorflow-importerror-libcusolver-so-8-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no)

I've tried to import tensorflow with tensorflow-gpu loaded in the uni's HPC login node, which does not have GPUs. It works well. I don't have Nvidia GPU in my laptop, so I never go through the installation process. But I think the cause is it cannot find relevant libraries of CUDA, cuDNN.

But, why don't you just use cpu version? As @Finbarr Timbers mentioned, you still can run a model in a computer with GPU.

Comment: I guess i am miss understanding something.  Do i install the cpu version on my development computer, the one without the gpu, and install the gpu version on the computer i plan to train on?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting? It is very possible to train on a GPU but develop on a CPU- many people do it, including myself. In fact, Tensorflow will automatically put your code on a GPU if [possible](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu).

If you add the following code to your model, you can see which devices are being used:

```
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

This should change when you run your model on a computer with a GPU.

Comment: I have installed tensorflow-gpu via thonny and used the validation code which tensorflow provides and i get the following error:
https://pastebin.com/5RxtH5Gx
I get the same error with just the code:

import tensorflow as tf

Comment: I have tried the code you provided and i get the same error.

Comment: The same error as the one i linked to in my other comment.  pastebin.com/5RxtH5Gx

Comment: Which version of CUDA do you have installed? I had that same error when I first setup my computer as I had installed the wrong version.

Comment: I have found the problems its like you said i should use the cpu version of tensorflow on my development computer and the gpu version of tensorflow on on the computer which has a gpu that can be used.

Comment: Okay, great. Another option you have is to use Docker to run your code; it's a one line change to switch from the CPU to GPU versions of Tensorflow: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/docker