# Difference between installation libraries of Tensorflow GPU vs CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently, I wanted to move my Python libraries to a pendrive to keep all the libraries constant while switching between my workstation and laptop. (Also so that if I update one, it's updated on other also.)

For this, I have installed a tensorflow-gpu version on my pendrive (my laptop doesn't have a GPU). Everything works fine without a problem on both PC (it detects and uses my GPU without a problem) and laptop (it automatically uses my CPU).

That's where my question lies. What is the difference between a

```
tensorflow-gpu
```

AND just

```
tensorflow
```

? (Because when no GPU is found, tensorflow-gpu automatically uses the CPU version.)

Does the difference lie only in the GPU support? Then why at all have a non GPU version of tensorflow?

Also, is it alright to proceed like this? Or should I create virtual environments to keep separate installations for CPU and GPU?

The closest answer I can find is
[How to develop for tensor flow with gpu without a gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290326/how-to-develope-for-tensor-flow-with-gpu-without-a-gpu).

But it only specifies that it's completely okay to use tensorflow-gpu on a CPU platform, but it still does not answer my first question. Also, the answer might be outdated as tensorflow keeps releasing new updates.

I had installed the tensorflow-gpu version on my workstation with GTX 1070 (Thus a successful install).

Also I understand the difference is that `pip install tensorflow-gpu` will require CUDA enabled device to install, but my question is more towards the usage of the libraries because I am not getting any problems when using the `tensorflow-gpu` version on my laptop (with no GPU) and all my scripts run without any error.

(Also removed pip install from above to avoid confusion)

Also, isn't running `tensorflow-gpu` on a system with no GPU the same as setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1`?

Comment: `tensorflow-gpu` depends on CUDA, and (at least until recent versions, and I believe it has not changed) trying to import it without CUDA installed (the right version of CUDA and CUDNN, that is) will fail. `tensorflow-cpu` will always work after it is installed correctly.

Comment: Importing tensorflow-gpu with out CUDA results in no error and works like a charm. I just checked it again right now to be sure. Edit: I also checked the tensorflow version and it is tensorflow-gpu and not the cpu version.

Comment: How did you install `tensorflow-gpu`? If you got [this distribution](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu) (e.g. with `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu`), I think it bundles CUDA/CUDNN in the environment for you (that is not something standard `pip` would be able to do, I think... and still, it makes it significantly bigger and slower to load).

Comment: I installed it on my workstation (thus successful installation) and then used it on my laptop. I will mention it in the question also for clarification.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Updated answer 2023 (Tensorflow 2.x and above:)**

Verify the CPU setup:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([100, 100])))"
```

If a tensor is returned, you've installed TensorFlow successfully.

Verify the GPU setup:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

If a list of GPU devices is returned, you've installed TensorFlow successfully.

[Source: Tensorflow installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

**Old answer(Tensorflow 1.x):**

One thing to Note: CUDA can be installed even if you don't have a GPU in your system.

For packages `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` I hope this clears the confusion. **yes/no** means "*Will the package work out of the box when executing* `import tensorflow as tf`"? Here are the differences:

```
| Support for TensorFlow libraries | tensorflow | tensorflow-gpu  |
| for hardware type:               |    tf      |     tf-gpu      |
|----------------------------------|------------|-----------------|
| cpu-only                         |    yes     |   no (~tf-like) |
| gpu with cuda+cudnn installed    |    yes     |   yes           |
| gpu without cuda+cudnn installed |    yes     |   no (~tf-like) |
```

Edit: Confirmed the `no` answers on a `cpu-only` system and the `gpu without cuda+cudnn installed` (by removing CUDA+CuDNN env variables).

`~tf-like` means even though the library is `tensorflow-gpu`, it would behave like `tensorflow` library.

Comment: Can I get a source for this? Coz my situation seems to contradict the information as I can run `tensorflow-gpu` on a system with cpu (with no gpu)

Comment: What's the `tensorflow-gpu` version you're testing this on? I tested `tensorflow-gpu` on 1.4.0 and the latest one, both on a `cpu-only`. None of them worked, as expected.

Comment: @RohanPooniwala Please do a pip/pip3 freeze and grep tensorflow. I think you must have a version conflict with multiple installs.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, had been busy with some stuff.. Also it turned out my environment had CUDA installed in it (some how, I have no idea why) and that's why it was working on my laptop without the GPU... Also `pip freeze | grep tensorflow` gives `tensorflow-gpu==1.11.0`

Comment: @RohanPooniwala So this corroborates with my answer. GPU with cuda+cudnn installed. All it would do is skip the gpu if not found and resume it on cpu. Try running the "nvidia-smi" command and check gpu properties of your laptop. Just in case.

Comment: Yes, GPU with CUDA+cudnn installed without an actual GPU in the system works.. It would be great if you can update your answer and mention it!

Comment: @RohanPooniwala Done!

Answer (score 21):

Just a quick (unnecessary?) note... from TensorFlow2.0 onwards these are not separated, and you simply install tensorflow (as this includes GPU support if you have an appropriate card/CUDA installed).

Comment: @Ironkey The only reason that I thought it worth an answer is that the OP's question most probably a bit dated in that there is now no longer any difference on the install (as there's now only one version on the current stream). I appreciate that it's been two years, but there's a lot of references online to TensorFlow-GPU

Comment: It's from tensorflow==1.15.0 and onwards, except for tensorflow==2.0.0. tensorflow==2.0.0 does not support GPU. tensorflow==1.15.0 does.

Answer (score 5):

`tensorflow-gpu` requires cuda/cudnn. `tensorflow` does not. `pip` doesn't install cuda for you (`conda` does), so `pip install tensorflow-gpu` won't work out of the box on most systems without a nvidia gpu.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with you, But again, pip install tensorflow-gpu was run on system with CUDA enable device (My workstation with GTX1070). And then importing tensorflow was success and all my scripts ran on a system with no CUDA device (My laptop with no GPU) without a problem.

Comment: @RohanPooniwala I just installed tensorflow-gpu via pip and got an error when I imported tensorflow. Do you happen to have anaconda with cuda hidden somewhere?

Comment: So like i mentioned in my previous comment, i installed it on my workstation (thus successful installation) and then used it on my laptop.

Comment: Sorry i misread your previous comment. I installed everything when i was on my workstation. The Anaconda also resides on the pendrive, but the CUDA installation was done only on the workstation and tensorflow-gpu was installed using `pip` and not `conda`.