# How can I install Tensorflow and CUDA drivers?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a clean install of CUDA drivers and TensorFlow, but I cannot get TensorFlow to use my CUDA drivers.

My version of Windows 11 Pro is 22H2.

I'm running Anaconda Python 3.9.15.

Here is the information on my CUDA drivers (by running nvidia-smi):

```
Sat Apr  8 16:44:56 2023
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 531.14                 Driver Version: 531.14       CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                      TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 S...  WDDM | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P8               10W /  N/A|   2049MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

My installation of TensorFlow showed:

```
>pip install tensorflow
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras<2.11,>=2.10.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers>=2.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (23.1.21)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.6 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=1.0.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: libclang>=13.0.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (14.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.27.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.1.1 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.11,>=2.10.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.46.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (65.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse>=1.6.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<3.20,>=3.9.2 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.19.6)
Requirement already satisfied: gast<=0.4.0,>=0.2.1 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py>=2.9.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.1 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel<1.0,>=0.23.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from astunparse>=1.6.0->tensorflow) (0.40.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<3,>=1.6.3 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (2.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-data-server<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=1.0.1 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (2.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (3.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (0.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (5.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=4.4 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (6.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.1.1 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from werkzeug>=1.0.1->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.4->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (3.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in h:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10->tensorflow) (3.2.2)
```

When I run the following test it shows that TensorFlow cannot find the CUDA driver

```
>python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
[]
```

Comment: Did you install `tensorflow-gpu` or `tensorflow`? By the looks of your output, you have `tensorflow`, but you really need `tensorflow-gpu`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if there are any issues with your CUDA installation:

   *nvcc -V*
2. Verify that you have set the environment variables correctly:
   *CUDA_HOME: The path to the
   CUDA installation directory.
   PATH: The path to the CUDA and cuDNN bin directories.
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH: The path to the CUDA and cuDNN library directories.*
3. if TensorFlow is detecting your GPU:

   import tensorflow as tf
   print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

Comment: nvcc looks ok,\.  I got: H:\HedgeTools>nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Feb__8_05:53:42_Coordinated_Universal_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.66
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32415258_0

Comment: Pls take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67084512/tensorflow-after-1-15-no-need-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-package

Comment: Go to: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native_1.  It says: "Caution: TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows."  Oh well, so much for TensorFlow!  I tried a Julia ML App and I found that Julia found my CUDA drivers and Julia used them!

Answer (score 0):

There is a note on the TensorFlow native Windows [installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native_1) that:

> TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to install [TensorFlow in WSL2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-%5Bwsl2%5D), or install `tensorflow-cpu` and, optionally, try the [TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml-plugin#tensorflow-directml-plugin-).

So if you want to stick with Windows your options are as follows:

1. [Use](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) an older version of [Tensorflow-GPU](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/) `<= 2.10`, and ensure you are using the requirements from the [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) for Windows with GPU support. For example, `tensorflow-gpu` versions 2.8 through 2.10 were tested with Python 3.7-3.10, cuDNN 8.1 and CUDA 11.2.
2. [Install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2) the Windows Subsystem for Linux ([WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/wsl/install)) on a Windows system running Windows 10 19044 or higher. WSL allows one to run a Linux distribution (default is Ubuntu but others can be used) to use Linux applications, utilities etc. directly on Windows without modification or the overhead of virtual machines. Again, one must also ensure they are using [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) for Linux with GPU support. For example, the latest version of TensorFlow at the time of writing this is 2.12 which requires Python version 3.8-3.11, cuDNN 8.6 and CUDA 11.8.

If you want to get serious about development, [care about your data and privacy](https://youtu.be/IT4vDfA_4NI), and experience the [benefits](https://opensource.com/life/15/12/why-open-source) of the free and open-source software community, the better option is to move to Linux (assuming you have control over the system and what OS it uses).