# Importing tensorflow in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have installed tensorflow with gpu support in ubuntu and can run it in an interactive python shell. However, when I am running the python file in pycharm, I am getting the error

`ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime`

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558707/tensorflow-importerror-libcusolver-so-8-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no

Comment: Make sure the library is listed in Settings/Project../Project Interpreter, and that you've set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your run configuration.