# Apache, Flask & Tensorflow - "ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, apache, amazon-ec2, tensorflow

I am trying to deploy a flask (python 3.5) application on an AWS EC2 instance using Apache2 that utilizes the GPU for a tensorflow model (AWS Deep Learning AMI - CUDA 8). And I am receiving the following error:

```
ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file
or directory
```

I have seen various iterations of this problem across StackOverflow and GitHub including, here:
[Tensorflow: ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558707/tensorflow-importerror-libcusolver-so-8-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no).

However these do not seem to apply to this case, because I only receive this error when deploying with Apache (it works fine when using Flask's in-built development server, or running the associated scripts manually).

Could anyone provide information as to why I might be receiving this error using Apache only and how I might seek to rectify it?

Comment: How did you configure your Apache server?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue, using some information found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4547. I was ignorant to the fact that Apache2 would ignore system level environment variables, and that they had to be set separately.

I needed to set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64` in the Apache2 Environment Variables config file, which I found at `/etc/apache2/envvars`.