# Tensorflow not recognizing GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am running one file in google colab which has dependencies of **Python3.6 and Tensorflow==1.3.0**
but while running i am getting this warning being GPU enabled from the run time.

```
2021-07-15 11:38:30.360422: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2021-07-15 11:38:30.360460: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2021-07-15 11:38:30.360471: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2021-07-15 11:38:30.360482: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2021-07-15 11:38:30.360491: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
Creating model with fresh parameters.
```

i tried installing tensorflow-gpu==1.3.0 at that time i am getting different error like this

```
ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I want to utilize GPU not hiding the warnings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow: ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558707/tensorflow-importerror-libcusolver-so-8-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no)

Comment: Tensorflow version that you are using is very old. Google colab might not configure Tfv 1.3.0 version. Instead use Tensorflow-gpu==1,13.1. Google colab supports Tfv1.13.1 GPU version . Thanks!